# Import MS SQL DB to MYSQL DB in cron

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I need to import MSSQL DB twice a day to MYSQL DB. 
Is there a way to achieve this by php script. 
I have founded many articles on the internet but end up in nothing.

Comment: How come all those many articles end up in NOTHING ?! What have you tried already?

Comment: I founded mysql workbench ia m tring this one